# Why MS Visual Studio 2008 has 2 copies of <sstream> STL file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl

This and this.

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\sstream"

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\sstream"

And the files have small differences. Why 2 files ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the files are different, but the one in the src directory is part of the runtime library source, and shouldn't be used by users of the library. The other file is the one included when you do `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: Thank you Amnon. I stumbled upon it when got difficulties with compiling some project and started cleaning unnecessary libraries from everywhere on machine. The presence of INCLUDE environment variable for .NET studio 2003 was the cause of compilation failure in Studio 2008. Wiping the .NET 2003 now.